# Handling and Cleaning Unstructured data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a set of unstructured data in the pandas dataframe which is of the following form

```
 1.  *COPLAND "At the River" from Old American Songs
 2.  *PUCCINI, arr. Stephenson</strong> "Tu, tu amore? Tu?" from <em>Manon Lescaut</em>
 3.  "Schulhoff / Arr. Honeck / Orch. Ille</h2>
     </div>
     <div>
     <p>Five Pieces for String Quartet"
 4.  >GINASTERA </strong><em>Variaciones concertantes
```

and so on...

The output should look like:

```
1.  COPLAND                                "At the River" from Old American Songs
2.  PUCCINI, arr. Stephenson               Tu, tu amore? Tu?" from Manon Lescaut
3.  Schulhoff, Arr. Honeck, Orch. Ille     Five Pieces for String Quartet
4.  GINASTERA                              Variaciones concertantes
```

Comment: Since it looks like you are scraping html I would recommend solving this issue with BeautifulSoup instead since there is no clear pattern. See [beautifulSoup docs](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more information.

Comment: @Oddaspa is it possible to do the first two rows with beautiful soup... i have thousands of data similar to this. Bit out of ideas.

Comment: Are you trying to divide them into two columns? Or would just a string containing the information be sufficient?

Comment: Need to divide them into two columns...

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I can't see a pattern in your data that would help solve your issue.

Comment: If there is no pattern is it an impossible task ?

Comment: I assume so. It seems like you want to separate composers and their songs, but with no clear division between them. I do not see a way to do this generically, you could make a white list of composers so that you split the string based on that. Then it would leave you with only the song.